# the php source code for php sprintf function

Tags: php, printf

Now I have one question about how to view the source code of `sprintf` php funciton. Because I want to know where and how is the function executes.
I could find some function, such as round function in the math.c by `grep -r 'PHP_FUNCTION(round)'`, but sprintf is not similar with round function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this simple question, I should grep 'sprintf'.

Comment: `grep PHP_FUNCTION(user_sprintf)` guessing the prefix is because C already has a function with the same name

Comment: *"Because I want to know where and how is the function executes"* -- it runs when you call it and nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 good ways to view the PHP source.

First and easiest is by using your IDE. For example in Netbeans `ctrl+right click` on any function will take you to it's source. This method is without a doubt the fastest, and when writing code it's the easiest place to goto to understand how the function works.

However you won't always get the complete source. Using `sprintf` as an example you simply get the following.

```
/**
 * (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)<br/>
 * Return a formatted string
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php
 * @param string $format <p>
 * The format string is composed of zero or more directives:
 * ordinary characters (excluding %) that are
 * copied directly to the result, and conversion
 * specifications, each of which results in fetching its
 * own parameter. This applies to both <b>sprintf</b>
 * and <b>printf</b>.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * Each conversion specification consists of a percent sign
 * (%), followed by one or more of these
 * elements, in order:
 * An optional sign specifier that forces a sign
 * (- or +) to be used on a number. By default, only the - sign is used
 * on a number if it's negative. This specifier forces positive numbers
 * to have the + sign attached as well, and was added in PHP 4.3.0.
 * @param mixed $args [optional]
 * @param mixed $_ [optional]
 * @return string a string produced according to the formatting string
 * <i>format</i>.
 */
function sprintf(string $format, $args = null, $_ = null): string {}
```

For 99% of use cases I feel the above is more than adequate for understanding how the function is working and most importantly, how to use it.

The other and more foolproof way is to checkout the [PHP Git](https://github.com/php/php-src/). Here is the actual source for `sprintf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include "php.h"
#ifdef PHP_WIN32
#include "config.w32.h"
#else
#include <php_config.h>
#endif

PHPAPI int
php_sprintf (char*s, const char* format, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  int ret;

  va_start (args, format);
  s[0] = '\0';
  ret = vsprintf (s, format, args);
  va_end (args);
  return (ret < 0) ? -1 : ret;
}
```

Source: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/php_sprintf.c

Comment: The source code you posted is not the code of the PHP [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function. There is no such thing as `char *` in PHP and the PHP version of `sprintf()` returns a string, not a number. This is an alternative implementation of `sprintf()` that PHP uses internally instead of the one provided by the standard C library when the standard one does not adhere to the C99 standard of the C language.

Comment: Isn't all of the PHP core actually C?

Comment: PHP is written in C, indeed. The interpreter and also the PHP functions. My point was that the code you posted doesn't run when a PHP script executes `sprintf("...")`. This code runs inside the interpreter and it is also part of the implementation of many PHP functions (`password_hash()`, `addcslashes()` etc.) but not as part of the `*printf()` PHP functions.

Answer (score 1):

PHP implementation uses the [`php_formatted_print()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/9e29f841ce3711488781be958ffdfc42d738de4a/ext/standard/formatted_print.c#L361) internal function that does the processing for all the `*printf()` PHP functions ([`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php), [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), [`fprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fprintf.php), [`vprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vprintf.php), [`vsprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php), [`vfprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vfprintf.php)). They all do similar processing, only the destination of the output differs.

The C function [`user_sprintf()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/9e29f841ce3711488781be958ffdfc42d738de4a/ext/standard/formatted_print.c#L660) (named this way to avoid conflicting with the `sprintf()` function provided by the standard C library) is declared as [the implementation](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/6035ebd4a6c2c81eaf7b2ac71f6e23cb04e2c000/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L2834) of the [`sprintf()` PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

[Its code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/9e29f841ce3711488781be958ffdfc42d738de4a/ext/standard/formatted_print.c#L660) is very simple (the hard lifting is performed by [`php_formatted_print()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/9e29f841ce3711488781be958ffdfc42d738de4a/ext/standard/formatted_print.c#L361)):

```
/* {{{ proto string sprintf(string format [, mixed arg1 [, mixed ...]])
   Return a formatted string */
PHP_FUNCTION(user_sprintf)
{
    zend_string *result;

    if ((result=php_formatted_print(execute_data, 0, 0))==NULL) {
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }
    RETVAL_STR(result);
}
/* }}} */
```

There are similar functions that implement the other `*printf()` PHP functions. They differ in the way they handle the value returned by `php_formatted_print()`.

Comment: Fair play. I think **avoiding** reading the php_formatted_print() source might be in everyone's interests, unless you want brain ache. What purpose do `php_sprintf` and `zend_sprintf` serve?

Comment: Also, if you look in main/php.h you will see on line 41 #undef sprintf
#define sprintf php_sprintf Does the source within /ext/standard/basic_functions.c then override what is defined in main/php.h?

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/6035ebd4a6c2c81eaf7b2ac71f6e23cb04e2c000/main/php.h#L41

Comment: No. The `main` directory contains the code of the interpreter. The `ext` directory contains the implementation of the PHP extensions; `ext/standard` contains the code of the [core extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/extensions.membership.php#extensions.membership.core) (except for `SPL` that is hosted in its own directory). `ext/standard/basic_functions.c` contains a list of structures (`const zend_function_entry basic_functions[]`) that tells the interpreter what C function (`user_sprintf`) implements a PHP function (`sprintf`) and how its arguments list looks like (`arginfo_sprintf`).

Comment: The lines 41-42 (`#undef sprintf`, `#define sprintf php_sprintf`) make sure the symbol `sprintf` does not already exist and then defines it as an alias of `php_sprintf`. This happens during the compilation of the interpreter and ensures the code of the interpreter uses `php_sprintf()` instead of the standard C library `sprintf()` that might be buggy. The PHP's `sprintf` is just a string in a table (`ext/standard/basic_functions.c`) in the interpreter's code. The interpreter calls `user_sprintf()` when it reaches `sprintf()` in a PHP script. The two `sprintf` (C and PHP) never touch.